# Javascript - building object with number of occurrence from another object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have an object with the timestamp and I want to build another object with number of occurrences based on the minutes from the timestamp

**Existing Object:**

```
{
    "data": {
        "dataArr": [
            {
                "fields": {
                    "@timestamp": [
                         "2022-10-04T22:45:17.482Z"
                    ]
            }, 
            {
                "fields": {
                    "@timestamp": [
                         "2022-10-04T22:45:17.482Z"
                    ]
            },
            {
                "fields": {
                    "@timestamp": [
                         "2022-10-04T22:46:17.482Z"
                    ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**My Code:**

```
let arr = [];
const occData = data?. dataArr.map(function (val) {
    timestamp = val.fields["@timestamp"];
    var myDate = new Date(timestamp);
    var minutes = myDate.getMinutes(); // converted date to the minutes
    arr.push(minutes);
    // Now I need to find the occurrences and build the new object
});
```

**Expected Result:**

```
{
    "45": 2,
    "46": 1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assumptions**

Your data was missing closing curly brackets for the `fields` objects, and I have assumed that because you're using map you want to assign output to the `occData` value.

I've also updated the usage of `var` and un-instantiated `timestamp` to constants as they are unchanging within their scope so do not need to be variable.

**Solution**

Following the convention of the method chaining style when using the `map` method on arrays, the typical way of converting the result to an object would be to `reduce` it.

The reduce function below is, for each `minute` value in the array resulting from the `map` function:

- Taking either the existing value from the accumulator `minuteObject` or 0 if that value doesn't exist and adding 1 to it
- Assigning the result back to the key for that minute value to the accumulator `minuteObject` and returning the accumulator for the next iteration

```js
const existingObject = {
      "data": {
          "dataArr": [
              {
                  "fields": {
                      "@timestamp": [
                           "2022-10-04T22:45:17.482Z"
                      ]
                  }
              },
              {
                  "fields": {
                      "@timestamp": [
                           "2022-10-04T22:45:17.482Z"
                      ]
                  }
              },
              {
                  "fields": {
                      "@timestamp": [
                           "2022-10-04T22:46:17.482Z"
                      ]
                  }
              }
          ]
      }
  } 

const data = existingObject.data

const occData = data?.dataArr.map(val => {
      const timestamp = val.fields["@timestamp"];
      const myDate = new Date(timestamp);
      return myDate.getMinutes();
}).reduce((minuteObject, minute) => {
    minuteObject[minute] = (minuteObject[minute] || 0) + 1;
    return minuteObject;
} , {});

console.log(occData);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you store the results as an object instead of an array you can get the intended results:

```
let arr = {};
d?.data?.dataArr.forEach(function (val) {
    timestamp = val.fields["@timestamp"];
    var myDate = new Date(timestamp);
    var minutes = myDate.getMinutes(); // converted date to the minutes
    arr[minutes] = 1 + (arr[minutes]||0)
});
```

Results:

```
Object { 45: 2, 46: 1 }
```